# Chrome Console | Reload or refresh only a specific element and not the entire page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console

I'm testing a page that has about 50 read-only fields, each one shows values ​​that come from a database. The page works fine, when a change is made in that field (in the database) the page shows the change correctly.

The problem is:

To see how the change is reflected I must refresh the whole page (with f5) and this takes a long time reloading the whole page from scratch. I need a way to use the **chrome console** to refresh just that HTML element (the one that contains the field I'm testing) and speed up testing. There are too many values ​​that I have to try: /

For example, I know that I can give commands to the browser from the console like the following:

```
document.getElementById("combo-1123-trigger-picker").click();
document.getElementById("combo-1123-trigger-picker").remove();
```

And those work. But, if I try something like:

```
document.getElementById("combo-1123-trigger-picker").load();
```

or something like:

```
document.getElementById("combo-1123-trigger-picker").refresh();
```

...it does not work.

Is there a way to update just one HTML element using the Chrome Console or the Development Tools?

Comment: Generally this is handled by the *live-reload* feature of your framework/bundler/compiler, it can be also added as a package explicitly, you'll have to look for examples yourself because the question doesn't describe your development environment.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm , thanks for the comment!

What I'm trying to do is ... reload or refresh this specific element or div from the same browser, using **chrome's Developer tools** (the element inspector I mean). Those code lines that I showed have the correct effect on the element when I enter those lines in the console of the same element inspector.

But the **load()** function doesn't do the effect I expect. To refresh this div/element without reloading the entire page with (f5).
I will update this question with a practical example.

Comment: There's no such built-in function.